# How do I find a MySQL ENUM-type column definition in Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a Mysql table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
 `entity` enum('CLN','TDS','TMS','VTMS') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CLN',
 `type` enum('INFO','STAT','WARN') NOT NULL)
```

How can I find what the  ENUM-type column definition is in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there would be a simpler way to find out the ENUM-type column definition but here's my solution:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Migration.select("show create table Events")
.first.values.to_s
.split("\n")
.select{ |line| line.match(/entity/) }
.pop
.match(/enum\(([',\w]*)/)[1]
.gsub("'",'')
.split(',')
```

-- select("show create table Events")
   -> 0.0004s

=> ["CLN", "TDS", "TMS", "VTMS"]